# Angular: How to Style based on the value of some of the properties

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get

```
 +--------------------+---
 | Title level 1      |
 +--------------------+---
 |     Title Level 2  |
 +--------------------+---
 |     Title Level 3  |
 +--------------------+---

<tr *ngFor="let report of activityResultsReportViewModel.reportList">
  <td [ngStyle]="'padding-left': (report.titleLevel.level * 5) 'px'">
     {{ report.titleLevel.label }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

This code is throwing an error.

How to add padding left? Level could be 0, 1, .., 6.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `padding-left` style attribute with these syntaxes:

```
[style.padding-left.px]="report.titleLevel.level * 5"
```

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'padding-left': report.titleLevel.level * 5 + 'px' }"
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pnyjyf) for a demo.